# Predicting missing letters in a sentence

Tags: nlp

I have the sentence below :

```
I want to b _ _  the car because it is cheap.
```

I want to predict the missing letters, using an NLP model. What NLP model shall I use? Can you give an example ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Recurrent Neural Networks, as a sequence to sequence task. Since it's a supervised machine learning method, you must have a dataset with examples of the corrections that you want the model to solve. After that, use a LSTM that returns sequences.
The dataset would look like this:

```
I want to b__  the car because it is cheap., I want to buy the car because it is cheap.
```

And the model would look like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(vocab_dim))
```

This is an example of model using Keras that can perform this task. May need some adjusts.